# List initialization rules

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, list-initialization

I want to initialize `std::vector<char>` with count and value.

This works:

```
int n = 100;
std::vector<char> v(n, 0);
```

However, list initialization `std::vector<char> v{n, char(0)};` gives me:

```
warning: narrowing conversion of ‘n’ from ‘int’ to ‘char’.
```

Is there a way to use list initialization syntax but avoid `initializer_list` constructor called?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, no.

When you're to list-initialize a `std::vector`, it'll first try to use the constructor with the [`std::initializer_list`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/initializer_list) parameter. Other constructors will be considered only if there's no suitable match.

Quoted from [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)

> - All constructors that take std::initializer_list as the only argument, or as the first argument if the remaining arguments have default values, are examined, and matched by overload resolution against a single argument of type std::initializer_list
> - If the previous stage does not produce a match, all constructors of T participate in overload resolution against the set of arguments that consists of the elements of the braced-init-list, with the restriction that only non-narrowing conversions are allowed. If this stage produces an explicit constructor as the best match for a copy-list-initialization, compilation fails (note, in simple copy-initialization, explicit constructors are not considered at all).

In your case, since type conversion between `char` and `int` is allowed, the constructor with `std::initializer_list` is used.

My suggestion for initialization a `std::vector`(and other containers) is don't use list-initialization unless you're initialized with a `std::initializer_list` and use copy-list-initialization only.

```cpp
struct A {};
std::vector<A> v1{100}; // ok, the size of v1 is 100
std::vector<A> v2(100); // better, the size of v2 is 100
std::vector<A> v3 = {100}; // compiles error
```